# How to add certificate to VSCode as we can do in WebStorm?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

Here is how it looks like in WebStorm:

[image]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes this question is probably a duplicate. I'm too lazy to look for the duplicate target, but I'll bet it's out there.